# How Express.static decides a relative path

Tags: node.js, express

All:

I wonder when I use express.static with a relative path like

```
app.use(express.static('./dist'));
```

How do I know what is the root directory? One interesting thing I find is:

If I run `node server/app.js`(all express server code is inside app.js) and put dist fold along with server folder, it works, but if I run `node app.js` inside server folder, then it does not. So does this mean express decide root base on some variables from Node?

Thanks

Comment: The "root directory" (I don't believe this is the correct term, but w/e) is the current directory the file is in.

Comment: if you were to use `./server/dist/` instead, the code in `app.js` would work.

Comment: @Derek Thanks, that is what I used to think, I thought `server` folder will be the root folder, and static will base on that, but why I can give `./dist` to `express.static` and put `dist` folder along with server folder(which is `../dist` to `server`)?

Comment: because the `./dist` folder is inside of the `server` folder. We need to trace our steps to the file or folder we want so we can include it

Comment: @Derek Sorry, I did not put dist folder inside server folder, but along with it. And I still use `./dist`, and it works with `node server/app.js`

Comment: ahh, then I believe it uses the location from which the application is called from

Comment: If you want to be sure, it is a good idea to use the __dirname and to concatenate your path: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));`